gdal_rasterize giving different pixel values
I want to count the number of polygons (in this case, protected areas) within a raster cell grid of a specific resolution. To do so, I have tried different approaches in R but, due to the database dimension, it takes too much time. I switched to gdal (I'm not an expert, I have used it a few times, but I often use GRASS GIS). Me and a colleague tried the same line of code on the same dataset (which is downloadable from here, and it is the WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp in the WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp_0 folder). This is his line:
gdal_rasterize WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp output.tiff -burn 1 -add -init 0 -at  -tr 0.01 0.01 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -ot Int32

And this is my line, which should do exactly the same, as only the paths are different:
gdal_rasterize /mypath/WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp/WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp_0/WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp /mypath/poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km.tiff -burn 1 -add -init 0 -at -tr 0.01 0.01 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -ot Int32

When loaded into QGIS, his .tiff has values between 0 and 6. My .tiff has values between 0 and 2221. Why is there such a difference? What is not working with my line?
EDIT: apparently it's a problem of my GDAL version on the server I'm using. I installed OSGeo4W Shell, run the command with the same dataset, and got the same output as my colleague.

Are both yours and your colleagues TIFFs in the same coordinate system?

Yes, it should be the same file, downloaded from the same source, without any transformation.

I suppose that max. 6 protected areas per 0.01x0.01 degrees area is correct, right?

Exactly. We now found out we are running two different gdal versions (we are using two different servers). I'll try to install a newer ones and see if something changes.

I downloaded file WDPA_WDOECM_Oct2024_Public_all_shp.zip (3.9 GB), but obviously it is not the same data that you have. How did you get your data "WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp" exactly? Edit - OK I found it.

This is likely related to GDAL Issue #8437 which counted polygon borders as well as the polygon itself.  Suggest you upgrade to GDAL 3.7.3 or later.
Using the following commandline including -at, I get max=32 with gdal 3.9.2 (from conda-forge) and max=14916 with gdal 3.4.1 (Ubuntu 22.04 repos).
$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.4.1, released 2021/12/27

$ gdal_rasterize WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp_0/WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km.tiff -burn 1 -add -init 0 -tr 0.01 0.01 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -ot Int32
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.
 
$ gdalinfo -stats poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km.tiff | grep Maximum
Minimum=0.000, Maximum=14916.000, Mean=0.152, StdDev=5.855

$ gdalinfo --version
GDAL 3.9.2, released 2024/08/13

$ gdal_rasterize WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp_0/WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km.tiff -burn 1 -add -init 0 -tr 0.01 0.01 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -ot Int32
0...10...20...30...40...50...60...70...80...90...100 - done.

$ gdalinfo -stats poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km.tiff | grep Maximum
Minimum=0.000, Maximum=32.000, Mean=0.056, StdDev=0.287


Yep, apparently it's a problem of my GDAL version on the server. I installed OSGeo4W Shell, run the command with the same dataset, and got the same output as my colleague. Thanks for checking that with a previous version.

I downloaded the data and tested it with GDAL 3.9.3 from OSGeo4W on Windows. I get the maximum of 6 result with a command
gdal_rasterize WDPA_Oct2024_Public_shp-polygons.shp poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km_no_at.tiff -burn 1 -add -init 0  -tr 0.01 0.01 -co "COMPRESS=DEFLATE" -ot Int32

gdalinfo poly_pas_1_wgs84_1km_no_at.tiff -stats
...
 Metadata:
    STATISTICS_MAXIMUM=6
    STATISTICS_MEAN=0.053004182013373
    STATISTICS_MINIMUM=0
    STATISTICS_STDDEV=0.27648704636177
    STATISTICS_VALID_PERCENT=100

With the -at switch (all touched) the maximum value is 32. I think that "all touched" is not good for additive mode, because then the border pixels between polygons gets burned twice and they get unrealistic, too high values. See the attached image. The purple pixels are touched by two polygons and they therefore higher value into the count field. This is not a bug. For this use case -at should not be used. In standard mode the intersection with a polygon is computed by using the centre of the pixel and a pixel can only fall inside one polygon.

There must be something unexpected going on when you get 2221 as a result but with the provided information I cannot guess what it could be.

Yep, apparently it's a problem of my GDAL version on the server. I installed OSGeo4W Shell, run the command with the same dataset, and got the same output as my colleague.

Related to this: why is it that the MAX value is 32 if I inquire with gdalinfo but when I visualize the raster in QGIS I see (also in the layer properties information) a MAX of 6? Mean and SD are the same.

You're either looking at the wrong raster in QGIS or the statistics in the .aux.xml didn't get updated. Try deleting {raster name}.tiff.aux.xml, re-running gdalinfo -stats and adding to QGIS again. I loaded the raster produced by the 2nd command (with GDAL 3.9.2) and it shows 32 in the legend.

If I remember right QGIS is computing by default estimated statistics from a sample of pixels. The same as approximated statistics in gdalinfo https://gdal.org/en/latest/programs/gdalinfo.html#cmdoption-gdalinfo-approx_stats.

@user2856 indeed, when reloading it, it showed 32.
